# Passing null for parameters in wcf results in object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wcf, nullreferenceexception

I trying to find a solution for this for a long time with no luck.

I have netnamedpiped srvice with the following interface

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SubTable))]
float GetValue(Table table);
```

when I call it in the client with null
    proxy.GetValue(tbl);

I get null expcetion since the wcf can not serialise the null
I wouldl like to be able to pass null with doing something like this:

```
if  (tbl!= null)
var result = proxyGetValue(tbl);
else
var result = proxyGetValueWhenNull();
```

Comment: What output do you intend to get with null input?

Comment: @shree.pat18 just internal logic in the server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the table as a property of another class and setting the attribute [DataMember(IsRequired=false/true)]?

```
[DataContract]
public class TableWrapper{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
    public Table Table{get;set;}
}

[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(SubTable))]
float GetValue(TableWrapper tableWrapper);

if  (tableWrapper.Table!= null)
    var result = proxyGetValue(tableWrapper.Table);
else
    var result = proxyGetValueWhenNull();
```